# Unix networking programming in C

Tags: c, sockets

```
/*
** server.c -- a stream socket server demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3490"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10   // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    (void)s; // quiet unused variable warning

    // waitpid() might overwrite errno, so we save and restore it:
    int saved_errno = errno;

    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);

    errno = saved_errno;
}


// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            if (send(new_fd, "www.luv2shop.net", 16, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Learning network programming in c

don't understand what's this piece of code doing and why we need it.
I am following Beej's guide to Networking programming.

```
sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }
```

code from server.c

Also what is that void sigchld_handler(int s) doing and where are we using it?

Comment: `what is that void sigchld_handler(int s)` what do you mean "what is doing"? `where are we using it?` what do you mean? It's used in the source you presented, what do you mean "where"?

Comment: sigchld_handler is a function that is set as the action when the program receives the SIGCHLD signal (indicating that a child has stopped or terminated). It waits for the child. (I think this is necessary for a server program in order to prevent "zombie" processes which occur when no other program ever waited for them).

Comment: `if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;` <<-- after closing the socket, there is no point in continuing. I think the `close()` should be omitted.

Comment: @wildplasser It is the `continue` that should be omitted, or replaced by `return`. Sockets have to be closed.

Comment: I misread. The loop starts with an `open()`, so it's Ok this way.

Comment: Actually he is missing a close after the prior failed `setsockopt()`. @wildplasser

Answer (score 1):

> what's this piece of code doing

It's registering a signal handler to execute on receiving the `SIGCHLD` signal.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC) https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

> where are we using it?

The signal handler calls `waitpid()` to remove the zombie processes. The code is executed when a child process terminates: the parent process receives `SIGCHLD` signal and executes `wait*()` call in a signal handler, notifying the kernel so that kernel can remove the child process.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process

> what is that void `sigchld_handler(int s)` doing

It is declaring a function named `sigchld_handler()` that returns nothing and takes one argument of type `int`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Answer (score 1):

The program forks child processes. It is the responsibility of the parent process to `wait` for them. That cleans up the child's entry in the process table. If you do not do that, your children will become zombies once they exit.

This code sets up a handler for the SIGCHLD signal. That signal gets send to the process if a child process ended. The handler then uses `waitpid` to get the exit status of all children that have exited.

Note that this program does not use the exit code of the children.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to wait for children if your program is not long-running (because the init process would inherit the orphans after the parent died, and wait for them). But "server" programs like in this example are supposed to run basically indefinitely, so the zombies would linger equally long; better to remove them from the process list.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica So it's a bob each way then?

Comment: @user207421 What is a bob?

Comment: @user Ah. Isn't "better to remove them" commitment enough?

Comment: It is only necessary for server processes. Other processes can happily ignore the issue. The reason I wrote the comment was to qualify koder's "It is the responsibility of the parent process to wait for them" and say "Not always: Unless you are programming a server you can leave that to init."

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica So you're still having a bob each way. You have said here (i) 'I think it is not necessary', (ii) 'beter to remove them from the process list'; (iii) 'better to remove them from the process list' again; and (iv) 'it's only necessary for server processes'. This *is* a server process, by definition, and you are just causing unnecessary confusion. Everything you have written here could be deleted without loss.